# Using "/blog" as a site with Wordpress Multi-Site

Tags: multisite, blog

I have Wordpress installed in the root directory, and plan to use the `domain.tld` as a portfolio and `domain.tld/blog` as personal blog site.

Since the `blog` keyword is reserved in Wordpress and can't be used for creating any child site, I tried changing the reserved words defined with `subdirectory_reserved_names` in `/wp-admin/network/site-new.php`. I was successful in creating /blog site. But the problem is, when I try to visit the `domain.tld/blog`, the error below is shown:

> This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?
>
> It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching, or one of the links below, can help.

This only happens when I try to visit the child site's homepage, but the pages and posts are fine. For example, I can visit the `domain.tld/blog/about/` page, but can't do the same with `domain.tld/blog`

What is the problem here? And how can I solve it?

Comment: If it's only going to be a portfolio and a blog, why on earth are you doing multisite?  Have your portfolio be pages and set your posts permalink to have /blog/ before them.  You will run into a LOT of issues with multisite, and I really don't suggest it for anyone who's not already intimate with WordPress core.  Also, this question has been covered many times before here.

Comment: I am fairly new to web development, and all I have been doing so far is playing around with Wordpress. I had little idea about the problems with multi-site since I never faced one.

Comment: http://halfelf.org/2011/dont-use-wordpress-multisite/

Comment: No problem - the best way to learn is to push the limits and then figure out why it's not working, so don't feel bad.  We all started out with no knowledge, and WordPress is a great place to start in web development.  The more questions you ask, the more you find out, so keep those questions rolling in!

Comment: Yes, that's the way I like to learn! Only that way you can know both the pitfalls and best practices from your own experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main problem is that you should never alter core files ... the next time WordPress does an update it might overwrite the file you just changed.

you should not have needed to use a multisite for your scenario - you can have a portfolio and blog in the same setup using plugins or a great theme (even without using something called custom post types).

I'm not certain of a fix but have a look at this and contact @Ipstenu or @AndreaR on the [Multisite forum](http://wordpress.org/support/forum/multisite) for why you shouldn't do this

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/subsite-taking-over-the-parent-site?replies=10

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. Now it's clear to me why what I did was bad.